# $\chi^2$ test - correcting for not fully independent sample

Tags: chi-squared-test, independence, sample

I have carried out a study in which I have gathered 3 sentences per participant. These sentences were then classified in 2 ways. I want to test if there are significant interactions between the classifications and find out the effect size. I have done a chi square test for independence and calculated Cramer's $V$ (on the counts of sentences for the cross of the 2 classifications).

However, I am concerned that this is not correct, since the sentences are not fully independent (because each participant has entered 3 sentences).

Is there a good way to correct for this (or are they other statistical tests that I should carry out instead of $\chi^2$ and/or Cramer's $V$)?

A colleague of mine suggested removing the sentences that were entered by participants who had sentences in more than 1 category of a classification.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what your data look like.  How does a "query" (in your last paragraph) relate to a "sentence" in the rest of the question?  But I've answered it on the basis of what I think you are asking.

Comment: Sorry I meant to write 'sentences' - edited. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I read this to mean that each sentence is classified in both ways, so you are interested in whether there is any relationship between the two classification methods.  If so I don't think it matters where the sentences came from - even if they are random or not.

The randomness that makes this a statistical question comes from the idea that under the null hypothesis the two *classifications* of each sentence are random and unrelated, and you are looking for evidence that this is not the case.  You are making inferences about the population of classifications, not of sentences.